# How to structure folders in nextJs 13

Tags: components, directory-structure, next.js13, app-router, kebab-case

## **1st Question:**

I saw some people that they are creating components folder inside a page folder
**Example 1:

```
src/
  app/
     gallery/
            components
            page.tsx**
```

On the other hand, I preferred this structure
**Example 2:

```
src/   
   app/
      gallery/            
            page.tsx
   sections/
      gallery/
            GalleryUploadForm.tsx
            GalleryPhotoList.tsx**
```

Which structure is better and why? Creating components inside a page folder or create a separate folder in src directory called sections and inside section I will create a gallery folder and here I can make all the sections or components for gallery page

## **2nd Question:**

Which filename style should I use in nextjs 13 **"foo-bar.tsx"** or **"FooBar.tsx"**? When I used nextJs 12 I always use to write filename like **"FooBar.tsx"** and I saw others also but recently I notice that when nextJs 13 released every one writing the filename like **"foo-bar.tsx"**, now I just want to know which convention is better and why?

I'm expecting to understand which structure is best for a large and industry level project.